# Python import errors

Tags: python, object, import

I've written a basic program with a couple of classes, and I've had two issues I would like help with.  All of the files are in the same directory, and my classes are in files with the same name as the class.

First, my class files can only import with the format

```
from module import class
```

I can't use the format

```
import module
```

Second, I've only been able to use my classes if I do the import inside of main.  When I import at the beginning of the file, I get an unboundlocalerror when creating an object.  I've had these issues (especially the 1st one) on more than one program.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, as you found out, use

```
import class
```

You either have to use

```
from module import class
```

And you'd call the class simply as

```
class   # note you don't have the module namespace
```

Or if you'd like to keep the namespace (which I'd recommend)

```
import module
```

Then you can say

```
module.class
module.otherclass
...etc
```

Comment: ObviouslyI wasn't clear in my description of the problem. My module name and class name are the same.  I canot use import module at all, even though the module name is correct.  I'm aware of the module name space issue - I can't access my class with the name space because the module won't load.  More confusing to me though is why I have to load it inside of main?

Answer (score 0):

As you found, you cannot just type:

```
import class
```

as that would lead python to believe that you wanted to import a module named class, when what you want is the class inside the module. That is why

```
from module import class
```

does work, as it shows python where 'class' is.